# Open hidden div from bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a hidden div on page which needs to be opened on click function.

The click-able link is inside the bootstrap popover so how can I get the page div opened by clicking on popover content link.

here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfkLM/10/)**

```
$( "#open" ).click(function() {
      $('.open-this').slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

Comment: really confusing.....will check okey

Comment: check out my updated answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this code:

```
$( "#open" ).click(function() {
      $('.open-this').slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

try this

```
$("body").on("click","#open",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      $('.open-this').slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

check out the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bfkLM/15/

The problem on your code is that the link is generated from your code and not presented in the dom when your event handler is trying to get it to attach the `click` event to it.

so the solution is to use **Delegated events**: 
from the official; jquery website

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

that's why my new code will work because it attaches the event handler to the `body` tag and checks that a click event is coming from my target element (`open`), when this happen it will fire up my code and the popup will be displayed

one more thing, the use of `e.preventDefault();` is to prevent the page from navigating to the `href` property of your anchor.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. I Need to scroll down to the page when click on the same a tag,But it is not scrolling down to the respective id.Any idea?

Comment: can you describe what is your scenario? do you mean that when the user click on the `open` link, the page should scroll down and display the popup?

Comment: Hey I got it.Thank you. Can u pls help with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158064/dismiss-botstrap-popover-by-clicking-outside

Answer (score 0):

The event is not attached to the link, because I guess you aren't doing it after document is ready.

For testing purpose I've added onclick function to the link

```
onclick="$(\'.open-this\').slideToggle("slow");return false;"
```

and it worked.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfkLM/14/%20Fiddle)

**Solution:**

```
$(function(){
   $( "#open" ).click(function() {
      $('.open-this').slideToggle("slow");
      return false;
   });
});
```